# SVG filter doesn't work at all

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to set up a Daltonian filter (i. e. an emulation of the various types of color-blindness), however, the SVG that I'm using for this completely fails. Firefox displays everything in the background color (everything is rendered, though, but is absolutely invisible), and Chrome displays the page normally.

Since I'm reading in the transformation values from a database, the SVG is generated by this Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT -I /srv/www1/cgi-lib

use strict;
use DBI;
use helpers qw(aindex);

my $dbname = 'DBI:mysql:<dbname>';
my $dbuser = '<dbuser>';
my $passwd = '<dbpass>';

my $p_http_ver = $ENV{'SERVER_PROTOCOL'};

my $p_debug = 0;

if($p_debug)
  {
  print "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n\n";
  }

sub get_params
  {
my ($l_script, $l_paramstr) = split(/\?/, $ENV{'REQUEST_URI'});

  return undef if(!defined $l_paramstr);

my @l_paramlist = split(/[&;]/, $l_paramstr);
my $l_this;
my %l_params = ( );

  foreach $l_this (@l_paramlist)
    {
my ($l_var, $l_value) = split(/=/, $l_this);

    next if(!defined $l_value);

    $l_value =~ s/\+/ /g;
    $l_value =~ s/%([0-9a-fA-F]{2})/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;

    $l_params{$l_var} = $l_value;
    }

  return \%l_params;
  }

my $params = get_params();
my %matrix = ( );
my @valid_modes = ( 'normal', 'protanopia', 'protanomaly', 'deuteranopia', 'deuteranomaly', 'tritanopia', 'tritanomaly', 'achromatopsia', 'achromatomaly' );

foreach (@valid_modes)
  {
# Fill in the normal matrix: Default for database failures!
  $matrix{$_} = [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ];
  }

my $p_mode = ${$params}{'mode'};
$p_mode = 'normal' if(!defined $p_mode);
$p_mode = 'normal' if(aindex(@valid_modes, $p_mode) == -1);

print "Content-Type: image/svg+xml; charset=utf-8\n";
print "Expires: -60s\n";
print "Pragma: no-cache\n" if($p_http_ver eq 'HTTP/1.0');
print "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate\n" if($p_http_ver eq 'HTTP/1.1');

# Empty line to end the header section...
print "\n";

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dbname, $dbuser, $passwd, { PrintError => 0, AutoCommit => 0 });
if($dbh)
  {
my $l_sth;
my @l_row;
my $l_i;

  $l_sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{select * from dalton});
  $l_sth->execute();

  while(@l_row = $l_sth->fetchrow_array)
    {
    for($l_i = 0; $l_i < @l_row - 1; $l_i++)
      {
      ${$matrix{$l_row[0]}}[$l_i] = $l_row[$l_i + 1];
      }
    }  

  $l_sth->finish();

  $dbh->disconnect();
  }

print <<"EOT";
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg>
<defs>
EOT

my $filter;

foreach $filter (@valid_modes)
  {
my $l_i = 0;

  print "<filter id=\"$filter\">\n";
  print "<feColorMatrix type=\"matrix\" values=\"";
  for($l_i = 0; $l_i < @{$matrix{$filter}}; $l_i++)
    {
    print " " if($l_i);
    print ${$matrix{$filter}}[$l_i];
    if($l_i % 4 == 3)
      {
      print " 0.000";
      print "," if($l_i < @{$matrix{$filter}} - 1);
      }
    }
  print "\" />\n";
  print "</filter>\n";
  }

print <<"EOT";
</defs>
</svg>
EOT
```

The following is used to attach this filter to the `body` element:

```
body {
  filter: url('/cgi-bin/svg/dalton.pl#normal'); /* substitute any other ID for "normal" here if required */
  }
```

When calling the script stand-alone in the browser, I get the document structure (no CSS present for the SVG), and validating it at validator.w3.org also didn't reveal any errors.
However, once I include it in the CSS for my XHTML documents, things start to go haywire (no, `-webkit-filter` doesn't make the thing work for Chrome, either...).

What could be going wrong here? Right now I don't see the forest for the trees.

EDIT: The script produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg>
<defs>
<filter id="normal">
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000, 0.000 1.000 0.000 0.000 0.000, 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000 0.000, 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000" />
</filter>
<filter id="protanopia">
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.567 0.433 0.000 0.000 0.000, 0.558 0.442 0.000 0.000 0.000, 0.000 0.242 0.758 0.000 0.000, 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000" />
</filter>
<filter id="protanomaly">
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.817 0.183 0.000 0.000 0.000, 0.333 0.667 0.000 0.000 0.000, 0.000 0.125 0.875 0.000 0.000, 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000" />
</filter>
<filter id="deuteranopia">
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.625 0.375 0.000 0.000 0.000, 0.700 0.300 0.000 0.000 0.000, 0.000 0.300 0.700 0.000 0.000, 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000" />
</filter>
<filter id="deuteranomaly">
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.800 0.200 0.000 0.000 0.000, 0.258 0.742 0.000 0.000 0.000, 0.000 0.142 0.858 0.000 0.000, 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000" />
</filter>
<filter id="tritanopia">
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.950 0.050 0.000 0.000 0.000, 0.000 0.433 0.567 0.000 0.000, 0.000 0.475 0.525 0.000 0.000, 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000" />
</filter>
<filter id="tritanomaly">
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.967 0.033 0.000 0.000 0.000, 0.000 0.733 0.267 0.000 0.000, 0.000 0.183 0.817 0.000 0.000, 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000" />
</filter>
<filter id="achromatopsia">
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.299 0.587 0.114 0.000 0.000, 0.299 0.587 0.114 0.000 0.000, 0.299 0.587 0.114 0.000 0.000, 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000" />
</filter>
<filter id="achromatomaly">
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.618 0.320 0.062 0.000 0.000, 0.163 0.775 0.062 0.000 0.000, 0.163 0.320 0.516 0.000 0.000, 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000" />
</filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: I have attached it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root SVG element has no namespace. You need your root element to be

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

Comment: Thanks. That actually solved it, and now at least Chrome is behaving the way it should. Firefox still displays a page entirely in background color, but that seems to be a problem inherent to that browser.

Comment: This is linked to the Content-Security-Policy HTTP header (denied by default-src) so a workaround would be to drop the header - but that solution is unsatisfactory unless I can figure out a way to adjust the header specifically for Firefox. This issue is already known, and there already is a bug report pending.